# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout should not show Toolbar fixed on top

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

In my `CoordinatorLayout` I have below arrange:

```
<DrawerLayout>
  <CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
       <CollapsingToolbarLayout
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
          <ImageView
               app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
          <Toolbar
               app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>
  <RecyclerView
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
</DrawerLayout>
```

I expect my custom `Toolbar` be hidden before scroll top.`ImageView` hiding when scroll top. every thing is OK but my `Toolbar` is fixed on top. before I do scroll. other behaviors are correct. Where I do mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar       
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are not using any scream color on your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. This should be like this:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:src="@drawable/picture1"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```